# Why does using .sheet(item:content:) in this view not work?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have two Xcode projects for the app project I am working on. In one project I am adding new things and testing and then when a new feature is built, I add it to the other project.

However, some of the files are different. I can identify the difference in these files but when I change.

Here is the code for the Test one (The one that works as expected and doesn't have any error messages):

```
struct LikedProductsTesting: View {
    
    @StateObject var LikedProductsModel = LikedProductsViewModel()
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    @State var product_id: String?
    @State var selectedProduct: String?
        
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let keyString: String? = defaults.string(forKey: "key") ?? ""
            
            VStack {
                
                Text("Tap to change")

                
                HStack {
                    
                    ForEach(LikedProductsModel.liked_products, id: \.id){ items in
                        
                        VStack {
                                                                                                                            
                            Image("ProductImage")
                                .resizable()
                                                            
                            Text(items.product_name ?? "")
                                .font(.title2)

                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedProduct = items.id
                            self.product_id = items.id ?? ""
                            self.showingSheet = true
                            print("Tapped... \(String(describing: product_id))")
                        }
                        .sheet(item: $selectedProduct) {
                            LikedProductsModel.fetchLikedProducts(key: keyString ?? "")
                        } content: { item in
                            ProductSheet(id: item)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onLoad {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let keyString: String? = defaults.string(forKey: "key") ?? ""
            self.LikedProductsModel.fetchLikedProducts(key: keyString ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

And here is that equivalent file (in the new project and this one gives the error: Instance method 'sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)' requires that 'String' conform to 'Identifiable. This error message appears on the .onTapGesture).

```
struct LikedProducts: View {
    
    @StateObject var LikedProductsModel = LikedProductsViewModel()
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    @State var product_id: String?
    @State var selectedProduct: String?
        
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let keyString: String? = defaults.string(forKey: "key") ?? ""
            
            VStack {
                
                Text("Tap to change")
                
                HStack {
                    
                    ForEach(LikedProductsModel.liked_products, id: \.id){ items in
                        
                        VStack {
                                                                                                   
                            Image("ProductImage")
                                .resizable()
                                                            
                            Text(items.product_name ?? "")

                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedProduct = items.id
                            self.product_id = items.id ?? ""
                            self.showingSheet = true
                            print("Tapped... \(String(describing: product_id))")
                        }
                        .sheet(item: $selectedProduct) {
                            LikedProductsModel.fetchLikedProducts(key: keyString ?? "")
                        } content: { item in
                            ProductSheet(id: item)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onLoad {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let keyString: String? = defaults.string(forKey: "key") ?? ""
            self.LikedProductsModel.fetchLikedProducts(key: keyString ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

ProductSheet view is the same in both projects. Here it is:

```
struct ProductSheet: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @StateObject var MarketplaceModel = MarketplaceViewModel()
    @StateObject var LikedProductsModel = LikedProductsViewModel()
    @State var selectedProduct : ProductTile!
    @State var someData = ""
    @State var id = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            
            VStack {
                
                if MarketplaceModel.products.isEmpty{
                    Spacer()
                    ProgressView()
                    Spacer()
                }
                else {
                    ScrollView {
                        
                        ForEach(MarketplaceModel.filteredProduct){product in
                            
                            ProductView(productData: product)
                                .onTapGesture( perform: {
                                    someData = product.id ?? ""
                                    selectedProduct = product
                                    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                                    let keyString: String? = defaults.string(forKey: "key") ?? ""
                                    
                                    LikedProductsModel.addLikedProduct(key: keyString ?? "", current_id: id, new_id: someData ) { (success) in
                                        
                                        if success {
                                            dismiss()
                                            print("dismiss")
                                        } else {
                                            print("Unsuccessful...")
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                    .onAppear(perform: {
                        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                        let keyString = defaults.string(forKey: "key") ?? ""
                        self.MarketplaceModel.fetchProductData(key: keyString)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the error "Instance method 'sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)' requires that 'String' conform to 'Identifiable" appearing on the LikedProducts view but not the LikedProductsTesting view?

The only way I get the sheet to appear on the LikedProducts()

```
 .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                            ProductSheet(id: selectedProduct ?? "")
                        }
```

But this will not provide the required function for the project.

Comment: do a project search for `extension String`. It may be that there is a file which contains an extension of the String class to make it conform to Identifiable which is missing in the other project.

Comment: take the `.sheet(item: $selectedProduct)` out of the `ForEach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the test project I had an extension String. I didn't have this in the newer project. This is why I was getting the error.

Here is the extension I added that fixed the error:

`extension String: Identifiable { public var id: String { self } }`